# Отключить удаление новых строк в Bash

Tags: bash, консоль, sh

Я хочу в переменную записать вывод команды `netctl list`. Если вызвать её в терминале, вывод будет таким:

```
* WIFI-1
  WIFI-2
  WIFI-3
```

Здвёздочкой "*" отмечен активный профиль Wi-Fi. Но, если попытаться записать этот вывод в переменную:

```
profiles=$(netctl list)
```

То все переходы на новую строку удалятся, как и звёздочка "*". То есть в переменной окажется:

```
WIFI-1 WIFI-2 WIFI-3
```

Как изменить такое поведение bash?

**UPD**:

Вот такой сценарий:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

profiles=$(netctl list)

echo $profiles
```

Вообще выводит

```
wifi.sh WIFI-1 WIFI-2 WIFI-3
```

Где "wifi.sh" - имя файла со сценарием. Ведь я нигде не вывожу это название.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они не удаляются на самом деле. Просто выводите не так, как надо:

```
x=$(netctl list)
echo "$x"
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйта. Как в выводе получается wifi.sh? (В вывод попадают все имена файлов из директории, где находится скрипт .sh)

Comment: @Don2Quixote  у меня вывод такой же, как если писать без скрипта. Запускаю через `./wifi.sh`

Comment: @Don2Quixote,  у вас оболочка разыменовывает звёздоку перед тем, как поместить в переменную. Отключите *glob*, и всё будет нормально.

Comment: @Don2Quixote https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388695/how-to-turn-globbing-on-and-off